# Explain a piece of Haskell code

Tags: haskell

Does someone knows what this code does?I know its validating the given year but I didn't really get the idea of the whole process.

```
tempYear <- getLine
case reads tempYear :: [(Integer, String)] of
     [(n, "")] -> do let year = read tempYear :: Int
```

Comment: Did you do this? It seems like the function 'reads' is different from it's usage and the 'do' is useless as the 'let'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess the `case reads` is there to deal with the case in which getLine does not return a proper number. `reads` returns a list of possible answers. If the tempYear were to start with a non-digit the empty list would be returned. If there was some other letter or something like that in the string, then the number up to that letter would be `n`. But the second value in the tuple would not be the empty string but the unparsed rest of the string.

However, I don't know why he would read an `Integer` first and then an `Int`. If the two types were equal, `n` would also be equal to `year`.

Answer (score 2):

`read` throws an uncatchable exception if you pass it a string that cant be parsed into an integer so if you want to accept strings that might motentially not be parseable you needd to use the related `reads` function instead. `reads` has a trickier interface: instead of returning a single integer result, it returns a list of possible parse results, and each parse result is the integer parsed together with the unparsed remainder of the original string.

- If parsing fails, it will return the empty list
- if you pass it "10asd" it will return an one-element list with 10 as the parsed number and "asd" as the leftover
- afaik, when parsing integers, `reads` never returns a list with more than one result.

In your case, he is using pattern matching to check if the return value from reads is exactly a list of a single element and that this single parsing results left an empty remainder (meaning parsing suceeded and got exactly one number)).

However, its kind of weird that he would reread the number as an Int. Usually you would just take the number from the reads result. (If you really need an Int, just tell reads to read an Int in the first place instead of Integer)

```
case reads tempYear :: [(Integer, String)] of
 [(n, "")] -> n
```

Additionally, the whole point of using reads is to avoid an unhandled exception but we will still get an unhandled exception if we dont cover all the cases in that pattern match! You still need to tell what to do if the parsing fails:

```
case reads tempYear :: [(Integer, String)] of
 [(n, "")] -> n
 _         -> 0  --return a default value?
```

If there is no sensible default value and you just want to "return null", the Haskel way to do that would be to return a `Maybe Integer` instead of `Integer`:

```
case reads tempYear :: [(Integer, String)] of
 [(n, "")] -> Just n
 _         -> Nothing
```